# C# Condition with call of function

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

EDIT: I try to do a condition with call of function like this:

```
public Channels Channel1;
public Channels Channel2;
public void Scale(string value)
{
 if((Channel1.Scale(value)) has been called) //I don't know if a syntaxe is possible for this
 {
  // do something
 }
 if((Channel2.Scale(value)) has been called)
 {
  //do something else
 }
}
```

Code for call in my Form:

```
Info pub = new Info(); // Class where i have my function Scale
private button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string value = comboBox1.Text;
 pub.Channel1.Scale(value);
}
```

Any idea for remplace 'has been called' by something working?

Thanks you for help !

Comment: What is `called`? this bit is a little unclear

Comment: @TheGeneral `Channel1.Scale(value)` , i try to find how to validate a call of this.

Comment: `public void Scale(string value)` where this method is defined!

Comment: d oyou mean "has been called"? You mean to check if the function has been called?

Comment: @Pac0 Yes it's what i mean !

Comment: Can you explain a little bit in detail about why do you need this information? I am asking because it sounds like there is a certain use case behind that and if we know the case we may find better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Channels`, add a `bool` property like this:

```
public bool ScaleHasBeenCalled { get; private set; }
```

At the end of `Channels.Scale(value)`, set `ScaleHasBeenCalled` to true:

```
ScaleHasBeenCalled = true;
```

Now in the `Scale` method shown in your question, you can check `ScaleHasBeenCalled`:

```
 if(Channel1.ScaleHasBeenCalled)
 {
  // do something
 }
 if(Channel2.ScaleHasBeenCalled)
 {
  //do something else
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you just need to know if the method has been called or not called:

As a *very basic* solution, you can have a property in your `Channel` class : `public bool HasScaleBeenCalled { get ; private set; } = false`.

You set this field to `true` in the `Scale` method.

Then in your `if` you can just check the value of this flag :

```
if (Channels1.HasScaleBeenCalled) {}
```

### If you need to check that a specific `value` parameter has been called:

Then you may need to do a bit more complicated: keep track of all the values used :

A field `List<string> ValuesThatHaveBeenScaled { get; } = new List<string>();`, and add a new value to this list each time Scale is called, and in the `if` you can check that `Channels1.ValuesThatHaveBeenScaled.Contains(value)`